# Is there a way to delete a scriptaculous autocomplete object?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I used the scriptaculous autocomplete to create a big page of editable fields, the amount of fields is dynamic, and therefore i create an array to hold all of the autocomplete objects.
then, i need to allow the user to add a field in every place of the page, so, i create a javascript function that redo the sequences of the text fields, and recreate all autocomplete's.
but there is a problem, that the old autocomplete's also appear on the page, and even if a make the array to length of zero, the old autocomplete's are hare.

Is there a way to delete completely a prototype object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete your DOM references, you do

```
bigAutoCompleteObject = null;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solved my problem, because although its stored in an array, when i empty the array, its doesn't delete from the Memory.

Comment: i used that, but the object is still in memory.

Comment: Alax; I admire you of your effort to help me, but that even when I delete the array completely, the autocomplete objects still live in the memory (my evidence is, that when i click on one item from the list, the text box is filled two times with the same value). i need some garbage collector method to clean all global autocomplete's objects.

Comment: i find a way to solve my problem without having to delete the values of the array, thanks anyway. i accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

- autocompleter holds references to input field and updater (popup element with possible choices)
- input field and updater hold references to event observers (methods in autocompleter object)

You need at least clear references stored in autocompleter object:

```
autocompleter.element = null;
autocompleter.update = null;
```